# CV2 imread PNG with colortype 4 (gray+alpha) reads as (x,y,4) array

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I have a png file with two 8 bit channels, however `cv2.imread(fname, CV2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)`.shape returns (768, 1024,4).  I have verified that the colortype field in the `IHDR` chunk of the PNG file is 4.

The PNG file was created with the latest version of gimp and I'm using 4.8.1 and also tried with 4.7.0.  I've tested on several images, and to create such an image I loaded a jpg image into GIMP, changed the imagemode to grayscale, then exported the image as PNG with pixel mode "8bpc GRAYA".

Using notepad++ w/hex plug in, the start of the PNG file is:

```
PNG header:
89 50 4e 47 0d 0a 1a 0a 00 00 00 0d 

then the IHDR chunk:
49 48 44 52    00 00 04 00    00 00 03 00    08 04 00 00    00
```

```
meaning IHDR fields:
Width:              4 bytes
Height:             4 bytes
Bit depth:          1 byte    (8 bits)
Color type:         1 byte    (4 = 4 is gray+alpha)
Compression method: 1 byte    (0)
Filter method:      1 byte    (0)
Interlace method:   1 byte    (0)
```

Why does `cv2.imread().shape` return a 4 channel array for a 2 channel image?

Comment: How do you imagine anyone can tell without seeing the image? Share it using Google Drive or Dropbox or similar if you would like some help. Also, click [edit] and add your [mcve]. Thank you.

Comment: Simply because OpenCV doesn't support this combination (grayscale+alpha transparency). I presume the first 3 channels are all the same?

Comment: @MarkSetchell, I should have an arbitrary PNG image with colortype 4 as it was tried with different images many times.  The image doesn't matter, its a 2 channel gray+alpha image that reads as a 4 channel image in cv2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a work-around, you can open it with PIL and convert to a Numpy array and work with OpenCV:

```
# pip install pillow
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

# Open image with PIL
im = Image.open('YOURIMAGE.PNG')

# Check size and type
print(im)
```

**Output** - shows image is "LA" mode, which is "Lightness+Alpha", i.e. greyscale + alpha

<PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=LA size=100x100

```
# Convert to Numpy array for use by OpenCV
na  =  p.array(im)

print(na.shape)         # prints (100,100,2)
```

---

I'm being over-verbose above so you can see what is happening along the way. You only really need:

```
na = np.array(Image.open('image.png'))
```

---

Note that you can make a (PNGtype=4) gradient image with a transparent hole in it with **ImageMagick** like this:

```
magick -size 640x480 gradient: -fill red -draw "rectangle 100,100 200,200" -transparent red -colorspace gray result.png
```

[image]

You can check its colour type with either of the following:

```
exiftool -ColorType result.png
Color Type                      : Grayscale with Alpha
```

or

```
identify -verbose result.png | grep png:

png:bKGD: chunk was found (see Background color, above)
png:IHDR.bit-depth-orig: 16
png:IHDR.bit_depth: 16
png:IHDR.color-type-orig: 4
png:IHDR.color_type: 4 (GrayAlpha)
png:IHDR.interlace_method: 0 (Not interlaced)
png:IHDR.width,height: 640, 480
png:text: 3 tEXt/zTXt/iTXt chunks were found
png:tIME: 2023-12-02T12:26:46Z
```

---

You can load it with **OpenCV** like this:

```
import cv2 as cv
im = cv.imread('result.png', cv.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
print(im.shape)        # prints (480, 640, 4)
```

It seems the grey channel is repeated 3 times as BGR channels, so you could discard the the green and red channels with:

```
twoChannels = im[:,:, [0,3]].copy()
```

Comment: Interesting - so the issue is with cv2 imread.  Otherwise it seems to support gray+alpha.   My work around makes the assumption it is a gray 2 channel image, and I just take channels 0 and 3.  Your work around is correct.  Thank you.